# Why is Python's json.dumps refusing to serialise strings from my objects?

Tags: python, json, django, string, serialization

My objects are not being serialised correctly from my Django site when using Python's `json.dumps()`. I've got a class which is designed to make the injection of data into [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) components:

```
class ChartData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.labels = []
        self.data = []
        self.background_colours = []
        self.hover_background_colours = []

    def add_datum(self, label, datum, background_colour=None, hover_background_colour=None):
        self.labels.append(label)
        self.data.append(datum)
        self.background_colours.append(background_colour)
        self.hover_background_colours.append(hover_background_colour)

    def get_converted_data(self):
        return json.dumps({'labels': self.labels, 'data': self.data, 'background_colours': self.background_colours,
                           'hover_background_colours': self.hover_background_colours})
```

A calling method takes a `Quiz` as an input, and adds data from its associated `Subject` items:

```
def get_subject_chart_data(quiz):
    subjects = Subject.objects.filter(question__quizquestion__quiz=quiz).distinct()
    chart_data = ChartData()
    for subject in subjects:
        chart_data.add_datum(subject.name, subject.question_set.filter(quizquestion__quiz=quiz).count())

    return chart_data.get_converted_data()
```

This converted data is then sent injected into the `context` for the page to be rendered.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(QuizDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    quiz = self.get_object()

    context['subject_chart_data'] = self.get_subject_chart_data(quiz)

    return context
```

Following this, it's rendered into an `{% include %}` statement, being passed in as the `chart_data` argument:

```
{% include 'snippets/pie_chart.html' with chart_data=subject_chart_data chart_id='subject_chart' chart_height=400 chart_width=400 %}
```

Finally, the HTML renders the chart using the `chart_data` passed in:

```
<canvas id="{{ chart_id }}" width="{{ chart_width }}" height="{{ chart_height }}"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("{{ chart_id }}");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: {{ chart_data.labels|safe }},
        datasets: [
            {
                data: {{ chart_data.data|safe }},
                backgroundColor: {{ chart_data.background_colours|safe }}
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Given how I've seen `json.dumps()` used in the below example from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), I would expect it to work.

```
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
```

However, it turns out like this:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ,
    datasets: [
        {
            data: ,
            backgroundColor: 
        }]
    }
});
```

However, if I pass each attribute of the `ChartData` to `json.dumps()`, as such:

```
def get_converted_data(self):
    return {'labels': json.dumps(self.labels), 'data': json.dumps(self.data),
            'background_colours': json.dumps(self.background_colours),
            'hover_background_colours': json.dumps(self.hover_background_colours)}
```

It works with no problems:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["Geo"],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [2],
                backgroundColor: [null],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [null]
            }]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not put the whole structure in JSON?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It was entirely in JSON, but I broke it down for the sake of a) Diagnosing the issue/trying something new, and b) To make the issue at hand more clear for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version of get converted data works because it is a dict and your template wants chartdata dot data and chart data dot background colours. The template is accessing the dict to get those values, which is why when you use a dict with json encoded values it works. The first version json encodes the whole dict as a string that the django template cannot read into.

You can transform your dict of python variables into a dict of json encoded variables like this:

```
data = {'labels': self.labels, 'data': self.data, 'background_colours': self.background_colours, 'hover_background_colours': self.hover_background_colours}
data_json = {k:json.dumps(v) for k, v in data.items()}
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that I incorrectly modified the code for purposes of presentation on SO. I'm using PyCharm, so the IDE tools would have likely picked up on that if it was the error. Will double check now.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not the issue. I will edit my question to rectify the typo now.